# how to use katex macros in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, katex

I just started using GitLab, and to avoid having the math and the code in different places, I would like to use the GitLab wiki to "store" the math. Writing the equation would be simpler if I had katex macros or definitions available. However, they appear to not be working.

I've tried all the examples in the Katex docs [https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#macros], making changes where necessary, but they do not work (i.e. do not render properly).

Example 1 (from the katex docs):

````
```math
\def\foo{x^2} \foo + \foo
```
````

is rendered as :

```
\def\foox2\foo+\foo
```

and not as x^2+x^2.
My institution has version 11.3.3 installed.

Comment: What version of GitLab, and can you tell (perhaps from HTML source) what version of KaTeX that is using?

Comment: @MvG The site help says the installed version is 11.3.3, which was released in October 2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\def` was added in [0.10.0-beta](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/releases/tag/v0.10.0-beta) but gitlab appears to be using katex `0.8.3` on [v11.3.3](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/v11.3.3/vendor/licenses.csv#L591).

There is an open issue for upgrading to `0.10.0` (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/56507) for the same reason you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is a matter of time.